# Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Failures.AdminActionConflictDetectedException: Conflicting Admin action detected

Tags: solr, xdb, xconnect

We were trying to rebuild the XDB index in `xConnect Index worker` webjobs.

We are getting the following error when we run the rebuild command `Sitecore.XConnectSearchIndexer.exe -rr`.

```
[Error] An error occured during resuming a previous index rebuild process. There will be another attempt to check. The check interval after an error is 00:00:20.
Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Failures.AdminActionConflictDetectedException: Conflicting Admin action detected.
```

Comment: Did you check this? https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/24764/xconnect-an-error-occured-during-resuming-a-previous-index-rebuild-process

Comment: Yes Sumit. I have seen the token in Solr Core

Comment: Did you move or copy your DB from some other places?

Comment: Yes, DB were copied from PROD and have updated the server name and database name

Comment: Sitecore version?

Comment: Make sure that you are not missing any marketing indexes as they have significantly changed from version 9.3

Comment: We got reply from Sitecore team to ignore this exception.

We could see processed documents in monitoring command and it is completed with 100%.

Sitecore.XConnectSearchIndexer.exe -rm